# How to know the domain ping of a server

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I need help. I have this command to execute.

```
wmic nicconfig get dnsdomain, ipaddress |findstr /i ipleiria.pt
```

I need to convert this command from a bat file to work next to another multicast program. I need to know the domain server ping of  ipleiria.pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wmic nicconfig where "dnsdomain='ipleiria.pt'" get dnsdomain, ipaddress


 wmic /append:"textfile.txt" path win32_pingstatus where "address='127.0.0.1' and responsetime > 100" get responsetime,timestamprecord
```